# Jetpack compose firebase convert anonymous account to permanent account (Gmail)

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, android-jetpack-compose

I've been trying to find any kind of way to convert an anonymous account to permanent one. I found the email/password and it does work. But I couldn't find anything using Gmail.
I checked [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?hl=en&authuser=0#kotlin%20ktx) but it doesn't but it lacks many things for it to work.
like how to get credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do that with a Google account too. Please check the below documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#google-sign-in

Since you're using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, I think that the following resource will also help:

- [How to authenticate to Firebase using Google One Tap in Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d)

Please also check:

- [How to link Phone with Email and Password Authentication in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091800/how-to-link-phone-with-email-and-password-authentication-in-firebase)
- [Delete other firebase authentication account and link that key to new authentication account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71854117/delete-other-firebase-authentication-account-and-link-that-key-to-new-authentica/71854930)

The same mechanism works in the case of linking an anonymous account to Google.

---

**Edit:**

Here is the code that will solve your problem. First, define a global variable:

```
private lateinit var resultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>
```

Then create a method in your activity class:

```
private fun initResultLauncher() {
    resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            val googleSignInAccountTask = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val googleSignInAccount = googleSignInAccountTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                googleSignInAccount?.let {
                    val googleTokenId = googleSignInAccount.idToken
                    val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleTokenId, null)
                    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                    auth.currentUser?.apply {
                        linkWithCredential(credential).await()
                    }
                }
            } catch (it: ApiException) {
                print(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And call it inside your `onCreate()`. I assume you're using Kotlin Coroutines. If not, attach a listener and see when the operation completes. This code will work inside an activity. If you need that inside a composable function, then check the code inside this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebasesigninwithgoogle/presentation/auth/AuthScreen.kt).

Comment: I do have authentication with google. Problem is the part of linking. like how I posted in link it does show code. but lacks parts of how I get credentials alone. if I do get credentials. Then I need to find a way to make rest of the code works.

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091800/how-to-link-phone-with-email-and-password-authentication-in-firebase) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71854117/delete-other-firebase-authentication-account-and-link-that-key-to-new-authentica/71854930) will help, right?

Comment: main part I'm lost at is the code to get GoogleIdToken which leads to getting credentials . I checked those you showed me before. but I mainly am looking for code which does it

Comment: I see. Please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Hey, Moon Sculptor. Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: Hello my friend, Sorry for taking so long. I ended up making a mix of all you've shown me. While adding the last part of starting the code from my normal sign in with google. Although main concern was making it work through a composable and having direct code. I managed to be able to do so by OneTapSignup from my project as a way to start the code.